# Add prebuilt apk to AOSP build

Tags: android, android-source, prebuild

I tried to include a prebuilt google apk (with no .so file) to my marshmallow AOSP build based on the information found in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579827/add-apk-files-in-aosp?lq=1) as follows:

1. In my vendor/manufacturer/device/proprietary/system/app, I created a folder named 'Testapk'.
2. I saved two files in this 'Testapk' folder, the apk ('Testapk.apk') and an Android.mk file which contains the following instructions:

> LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
>
> include $(CLEAR_VARS)
>
> LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
>
> LOCAL_MODULE := Testapk
>
> LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_MODULE).apk
>
> LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
>
> LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)
>
> LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := PRESIGNED
>
> include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)

3. I added the following instruction in my vendor/manufacturer/device/vendor_device.mk :

> PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \
>
> Testapk

When making the AOSP build, I get the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `/Testapk', needed by `out/target/product/mako/obj/APPS/Books_intermediates/Testapk.apk'.  Stop.

#### make failed to build some targets (01:00 (mm:ss)) ####
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with my `Android.mk` file was that it had trailing spaces on each line. Everything worked fine after I deleted these trailing spaces.

Answer (score 2):

after the \ the "testapk" should be on a new line.

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \ Testapk
```

Comment: Correct solution to the problem is this, other new lines has no effect to the problem.