# AOSP: Cannot pack presigned apk

Tags: android, android-source, android-signing

I build my project in Android Studio and generate signed apk, then put my apk in Android Open Source Project to pack my app with system image.
I followed [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579827) to pack my app with system image.
My problem is this line in `Android.mk`:

```
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := < desired key >
```

if I don't sign the apk and use

```
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
```

everything goes well and build is successful
but if I sign my apk and use

```
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := PRESIGNED
```

my build fails with Error 1:

```
make: *** [out/target/product/helpera64-v2/obj/APPS/MyApp_intermediates/package.apk] Error 1
```

for verbos log I make project with `make showcommands` and this is where error happens:

```
mv out/target/product/helpera64-v2/obj/APPS/MyApp_intermediates/package.apk out/target/product/helpera64-v2/obj/APPS/MyApp_intermediates/package.apk.unaligned
out/host/linux-x86/bin/zipalign -f -p 4 out/target/product/helpera64-v2/obj/APPS/MyApp_intermediates/package.apk.unaligned out/target/product/helpera64-v2/obj/APPS/MyApp_intermediates/package.apk.aligned
make: *** [out/target/product/helpera64-v2/obj/APPS/MyApp_intermediates/package.apk] Error 1
```

so the problem is zipalign! build system should not use zipalign for signed apk, but why does it use?

My full Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := MyApp
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := PRESIGNED
LOCAL_DEX_PREOPT := false
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT)/preinstall
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := my_app.apk
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE = true
LOCAL_OVERRIDES_PACKAGES := Home Launcher2 Launcher3


include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

Answer (score 1):

> mv out/target/product/helpera64-v2/obj/APPS/MyApp_intermediates/package.apk out/target/product/helpera64-v2/obj/APPS/MyApp_intermediates/package.apk.unaligned

> out/host/linux-x86/bin/zipalign -f -p 4 out/target/product/helpera64-v2/obj/APPS/MyApp_intermediates/package.apk.unaligned out/target/product/helpera64-v2/obj/APPS/MyApp_intermediates/package.apk.aligned

> make: *** [out/target/product/helpera64-v2/obj/APPS/MyApp_intermediates/package.apk] Error 1

From the error log, the `zipalign` command executed failed, so the potential failed reason is that your apk with wrong `align`. Maybe you can follow the [Android's zipalign](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/zipalign) document to ensure your apk with the correct `align`.

PS: I have encountered the similar problem because of presigned apk has wrong `align` so file.