# Adding System Apps to an Android Operating System

Tags: java, android, security, operating-system, android-source

I'm working on a fork of Graphene OS and I'm new in android development too.
How would it be possible adding a new System app into the build? E.g. Briar, that is an external App? Or generally how it can be done on a Android OS in theory? E.g a solution in lineage OS would be great too.
What have beem done?

Best regard and I hope someone could help.

I added my repo into the plattform manifest and did a folder of external/Apps in my repo.

Comment: So you have apps that require system permission and thus you want to add them?

Comment: Not only, I would like to add e.g briar that doesn't need System permission, but should be prebuild.

Comment: Okay in that case, the question is a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579827/how-do-i-add-apks-in-an-aosp-build , which you might want to take a look at.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add APKs in an AOSP build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579827/how-do-i-add-apks-in-an-aosp-build)